# Javascript Discord Bot not responding to interactions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm following this really simple Discord Bot tutorial using Javascript, and I'm running into an issue. The bot is able to login and all that, but when I actually use the slash command, it doesn't respond and CMD says:
`ReferenceError: interaction is not defined at Client.handleInteraction (file:///C:/Program%20Files/discord-bot/bot.js:18:5)`

I have the following code for my main bot file named bot.js:

```
import { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import * as bos from './commands/sticks.js';


config();

const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds],
});

function readyDiscord() {
    console.log("Hello " + client.user.tag);
}

async function handleInteraction() {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    if (interaction.commandName === 'sticks') {
        await bos.execute(interaction);
    }
}

client.once(Events.ClientReady, readyDiscord);

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, handleInteraction);
```

my actual command file named sticks.js:

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from 'discord.js';

// Command Builder export
export const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('sticks')
    .setDescription('Fun bundle of sticks!');

// Execute function export
export async function execute(interaction) {
    await interaction.reply('Sticks');
}
```

the deploy commands file:

```
// Importing modules using ES6 syntax
import { REST, Routes } from 'discord.js';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import fs from 'node:fs';

config(); // Using dotenv config function directly

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = await import(`./commands/${file}`); // Using dynamic import
  if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
  } else {
    console.log(`[WARNING] The command ${file} is missing a required "data" or "execute"   property.`);
  }
}

// Construct and prepare an insance of the REST module
const rest = new REST().setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

    // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
    const data = await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.CLIENTID,   process.env.SERVERID), {
      body: commands,
    });

    console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
  } catch (error) {
    // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

My .env file is also setup correctly with the right SERVERID, CLIENTID, and TOKEN.
I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but I can't pinpoint it.

I tried renaming the interaction names, reviewing my video reference. It's supposed to respond to a simple slash command of '/sticks', but when I do that it says "The application did not respond". I made sure to deploy the commands and log the bot in.

Comment: The `handleInteraction` function is using a variable called `interaction` which was never defined.  Where should that variable be defined?  Perhaps you mis-copied something from whatever tutorial you're using?

Comment: good point, then there lies where it should be defined and how...I'll have to check that

Comment: This isn't a discordjs problem, it's a basic JavaScript problem; you can't use a variable that you wasn't created. You've never defined the `interaction` variable, so why do you expect it exists?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the `interaction` variable. And seeing where the command is being used, I assume it's a parameter

```js
async function handleInteraction(interaction) {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    if (interaction.commandName === 'sticks') {
        await bos.execute(interaction);
    }
}
```